# Brant Carlson Quantum Mechanics YouTube video series. Could someone explain this product rule identity?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, products

Could someone explain the identity on the top right of the page please and how it is achieved.

[image]

Here is my working thus far. I tried using the product rule with $u= \frac{d}{dx}$ and $v = the longer term$ but this seems to get stuck as shown in the bottom line.

[image: My working thus far]

Many thanks,

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried using the product rule with $ u = \frac{d}{dx} $ and $v$ = the longer term but it seems to get stuck. Please see my question again as I will upload a pic of my working

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. Isn't your exprassion for $v'$ the identity you were looking for?

Comment: Yes thats right, which is obviously not correct. So I was asking how the entire identity can be shown

Comment: why is it not correct?

Comment: Because when I apply the product rule I get the expression in the final line of the second picture, which is not equivalent to the integrand of the on the top line of the first picture

Comment: I thought you were trying to prove that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}{(\psi^{*}\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}-\psi\frac{\partial\psi^{*}}{\partial x}})={(\psi^{*}\frac{\partial^{2}\psi}{\partial x^{2}}-\psi\frac{\partial^{2}\psi^{*}}{\partial x^{2}}}) $ This follows from direct application of the derivative and noting that  the $\frac{\partial\psi^{*}}{\partial x}\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}$ cancel

Comment: Yes I am trying to prove that very thing. I was unsure if I could directly apply the partial derivative to the expression inside the bracket... Someone mentioned use of the product rule which is where I got stuck. Where does the term in your last line come from?

Comment: $(ab)'=a'b+b'a$ apply the same to $\psi^{*}\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}$

Comment: Ohhhhh. I am sorry, I have been looking at this completely wrong. So simple now that you have put it like that!